# How to replace pojo object with a new instance of same kind?

Tags: java

I need to replace certain properties of the object with new ones. What is the best way to do it? It should be reliable that in future if we add more properties to it,it shouldn't break anywhere. I can create a method which sets for each property but this method needs to be modified everytime I add a new property to the object. Is there a best way to do it?

### Object

```
public class TangoObject {

  String a;
  String b;
 // so on
public void update(TangoObject to){
  setA(to.getA());
  setB(to.getB());
   }
}
```

**Now when executing below code**

```
 SomeService(TangoObject to){
   //call processor
    someObject.processor(to);
    doSomethingelse(to);
  }
```

### Processor code

```
class SomeObject {
   public void processor(TangoObject to) {
     TangoObject newTo = new TangoObject();

     // manipulate the new object to
      tangoObject.update(newTo); -- replacing original tangoObject with new one as some properties where changed
   }
 }
```

Comment: You have to either use reflection or [`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()).

Comment: Of course, the other option is to replace the old object with the new one, vs updating the old to match the new.  Requires that you be able to locate all the references, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with your approach. Everything is kept simple and readable, and you only have to change one method when you add a new property.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't like the method:

```
public void update(TangoObject to){
  setA(to.getA());
  setB(to.getB());
}
```

because it needs to be maintained whenever you add a new property to the `TangoObject` class.

You can avoid it by using a more dynamic way to copy the properties from one TangoObject to another.
You can use [beauUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to copy the properties. So your method becomes:

```
public void update(TangoObject to){
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(to, this);
}
```

And you don't need to maintain it as you add properties to the `TangoObject` class.

EDIT:
If you don't want to include BeanUtils in your dependencies, you can implement this functionality using reflection. Your case is easier if `TangoObject` doesn't inherit, because you can get all fields with `class.getDeclaredFelds()`.
You can do something like:

```
static <T> void copy(T from, T to) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz = from.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        fields[i].setAccessible(true);
        Object value = fields[i].get(from);
        fields[i].set(to, value);
    }
}
```

Actually you are not replacing the instance, but just its state namely the values of its fields. The instance `to` remains the same but the state of another object is transferred on it by copyingits properties.

Comment: I thought of it, but looks I need to add an external jar for it. Is there another solution for it?

Comment: Actually, I think the original proposal is much simpler.

Comment: @user1595858 Look edited answer how to copy state from one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy constructor but that would have the same limitations--no way to add a field without copying.

If you like the structure of having all the setters and getters and all the code using your "Pojo" will allow it, there is absolutely no reason you couldn't use:

```
public class TangoObject {
    HashMap vars=new HashMap();

    public String getA() {
        return (String) (vars.get("a"));
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        vars.put("a",a);
    }

    public int getB() {
        Integer i=vars.get("b");
        return (int) (i == null ? 0 : i);
    }
  ...

    public void update(TangoObject to){
        to.vars.clear();
        to.vars.copyFrom(vars);
    }
}
```

I'm not saying this is the greatest thing ever but if your class is just a bean class (Meaning nothing inside USES the variables except to get and retrieve them) then there is no huge advantage over even having separate variables. "Type Safety" is ensured by the setters and getters so it's no worse than the other solution.

Personally I really dislike the bean pattern.  I prefer pojos without setters and getters at all--where they have their business logic inside them and not spread throughout the code willy-nilly wherever they are used.  If your class doesn't have any logic, it shouldn't be a class--but this is not a common view by a long shot, in fact sometimes I think I may be the only one who feels this way.